# Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, symbols

[This demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2&ssl=2&ssc=14&pln=2&pc=39#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxAWwJYQKYwLwwApJqYB0CGEIANgG4YAUAlANwBQoksUIAylAgFwwoATzgYQAMxjdhyAEZViXXglRgA5gBUAhupgAfGNRCoAJjiGjxUmfKo5suAOQSArmGBRU4JzAD80rIKlEo8fGpaujCC7qYYEmoYpqwsqFJ0ynwMMADeLDAFMOwUlBjElCDqdIgo6BgA2pkIALoOzgS1mE7MLAC%20QA) makes `typeof Symbol.toStringTag` type `symbol`:

```
const promise = Promise.resolve();
const toStr: typeof Symbol.toStringTag | void = typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.toStringTag : undefined;

if (toStr) {
    console.log(promise[toStr] === 'Promise');
}
```

And results in error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'symbol' can't be used to index type 'Promise'.(7053)

Is there a way to narrow down `toStr` symbol type instead of using symbols explicitly like `promise[Symbol.toStringTag]`?

Comment: Do you really need to affect `Symbol.toStringTag` to a constant ? You could affect `typeof Symbol === 'function'` to `toStr` and use `promise[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'Promise'` afterward instead.

Comment: @Raphaël It could be another symbol that may not exist on Symbol like asyncIterator. Yes, it can be done with `const symbolAvailable = typeof Symbol === 'function' && !!Symbol.toStringTag` could avoid this but this would require to access full symbol name every time just to please TS.

Answer (score 2):

Stated that I'm not getting the same error, but I got a `true` printed on my console with following `compilerOptions`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es6"
}
```

Since you know that `typeof Symbol.toStringTag === "symbol"`, why not?

```
const promise = Promise.resolve();
const toStr: symbol | void = typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.toStringTag : undefined;

if(toStr) console.log(promise[toStr] === "Promise");
```

Once said that I think the key is `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` compile option. Don't know if it is a reasonable compromise for you.

Hope this helps

Comment: It can be easily reproduced in Playground, it doesn't have suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors option. Thanks, suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors is a workaround I didn't remember of. Not sure if it's worth it for the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, `typeof Symbol.toStringTag` is just `symbol`, which isn't specific enough for your purposes. The [`unique symbol` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol) is more specific, but I believe it's only for user-defined Symbols.

Would it meet your needs to use use an accessor function, rather than storing the symbol?

```
const promise = Promise.resolve();

interface StringTaggable {
  readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}

const toStringTag =
  typeof Symbol === 'function' ? (o: StringTaggable) => o[Symbol.toStringTag] : undefined;

if (toStringTag) {
    console.log(toStringTag(promise) === 'Promise');
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to not make runtime code more complicated to pass TS type checks but thanks for the suggestion, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a subject of a long passionate discussion on the [TypeScript github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20898). There are a few hacky ways of doing this but you will not be able to narrow the `symbol` type the way you can narrow down `string` to a string literal anytime soon :/