# TS(7015) in a document.form : "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type "number"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get values entered by a user in a form.

This is how my form looks like :

```
<form name="myForm">
   <span class="myFormSpan">+</span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="My answer" name="myFormUserInput">
   <button type="button" class="formButton">Ok</button>
</form>
```

I want to get what the user's put in the input form, so my typescript code looks like this :

```
formInputs.addEventListener("click", () => {
   const userInput: any = document.forms["myForm"].elements["myFormUserInput"].value;
   console.log(userInput);
});
```

which works fine, except that I keep getting a TypeScript warning `ts(7015) : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`. I've tried to change my code to `document.forms[0]`, which doesn't remove the warning, and tried to add some type specifications here and there without being more successful...

I would like to keep implicit warning on (contrary to the solution written there: [Element implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818643/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type)) because I would like to understand the issue and have a way to solve it

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: document.forms[0] is also giving you the same error?

Comment: Hi @TusharShahi ! Yes unfortunately... I tried that first and didn't change anything - which is why I don't get where the warning comes from :-D

Comment: Similar issue for me, using 0 cleared it but I don't understand WHY it's an issue in the first place. document.forms is an HTMLCollection and can be accessed using string instead of index. Unless the error Stebenwolf is getting is actually on the .elements section for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Using number-based indexes on forms and elements should clear the warning.

```
formInputs.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const userInput: any = (document.forms[0].elements[0] as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log(userInput);
});
```

**But you should realy consider to use document.querySelector()**

This will find the correct form/input regardless of position or order inside the DOM

like so:

```
formInputs.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const userInput = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('form[name="myForm"] input[name="myFormUserInput"]') || null

    if (userInput !== null)
        console.log(userInput.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the elements property from the HTML Form element, consider using a FormData Object. That way you are able to lookup a form value by input name.

```
formInputs.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const formdata = new FormData(document.forms["myForm"] as HTMLFormElement);
    const userInput = formdata.get('myFormUserInput');
    console.log(userInput.toString());
});
```

Comment: edit: I know this is an old topic, but I was looking for the same issue and found this to be the cleanest solution.